# AngularJS: ngInclude with custom scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an existing directive that creates a generic wizard that will be used across my current organization. This wizard will have steps, and each step has an HTML template to be loaded as the "body" of the wizard. Currently, I'm adding the template using ng-include. I don't know which attributes the wizard will have, as it will come from the wizard consumer.

**Question:** Is there a way to bind the template models (attributes) to a directive scope variable instead to the scope itself?

Currently I have:

**Directive HTML**

```
<div ng-include="/step1.html"></div>
```

Note: This step1.html is just an example. The actual HTML template will come as a configuration parameter from the wizard directive.

**Step 1 HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.email"/>
```

This is "forcing" the wizard consumer to include "data" for each of his attributes.

As a result, I was looking for something like this:

**Directive HTML**

```
<div ng-include="/step1.html" ng-scope="scope.data"></div>
```

**Step 1 HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using ng-transclude. Now, the consumer does not need to send me the HTML code (step1.html). Right now, this goes directly into the wizard directive body, as follows:

**Sample Controller**

```
angular.module('sampleApp').controller('SampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.email;
});
```

**Sample HTML**

```
<div wizard>
   <div step title="Step 1">
       <input type="text" ng-model="email"/>
   </div> 
</div>
```

**Directives with transclude option**

```
angular.module('sampleApp').directive('wizard', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
        },
        template: '<div> Wizard <div class="stepsContainer" ng-transclude /></div>'
    };
});

angular.module('sampleApp').directive('step', function () {

    return {
        require: "^wizard",
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="current"> {{ title }} <div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is a `directive`, with which you can have isolate scope, just like taking parameter from outer scope.

**Directive**

```
yourModule.directive('step1', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '=anyname'
    },
    templateUrl: "/step1.html"
  };
})
```

**Step1 HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.email"/>
```

Then when the consumer uses it:

```
<div step1 anyname="scope.consumerData"></div>
```

Then `anyname` can be named anything meaningful to the consumer, without knowing the template is actually using `data`.

Comment: Hi Gildor, thanks a lot for your answer. But this Step 1 HTML I don't own that. This is sent by the consumer of the application. This is a generic wizard and can have n number of steps. I can't have one directive per step. Also, this wizard is already a directive itself.

Comment: @AlanSouza The wizard being a directive does not prevent you making the step a directive too. And what's wrong with the Step 1 HTML?

Comment: @AlanSouza And how will the consumer provide HTML of the n steps?

Comment: Hey Gildor, the data is provided through a JSON object.